# Is it possible to display Google Maps circle without LatLong on the client

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor, maps

Sites like Airbnb and RelayRides show a rough area map to a user who has not yet booked the item because the exact address (or Lat Long) is sensitive, it should be hidden. This is basically the [circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/circle-simple) radius feature Google Maps.

However, is it possible do this without the Lat/Long reaching the client browser?

```
 GoogleMaps.ready('exampleMap', function(map) {
    // Add a marker to the map once it's ready
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.478644, 144.9631), // This is sensitive. If there is any way to hide it on the client.
      map: map.instance,
      icon: '/map-icon.png'
    });
  });
```

I am guessing the exact location is only hidden visually but the Lat/Long will need to be provided to the Maps function in the client side and so will have to be present on the client. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: You could randomise the exact point you send to the client. Ie add 0.0001 to the latlng or take away 0.000..3 etc..

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock Yes, that makes sense. I was thinking of something on the same lines. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DB, when each point is created, call a function to buffer that point (ie create a circle around that point). Then, instead of sending the latlng to the client, send the polygon. The turf.js library is good for this if you're not sure about the math (geodesics are hard). The downside is anyone with a brain & too much time can calculate the center VERY EASILY. Even if you randomize the point, I could rerun the calculation, determine the stdev, and find it with nothing more than a browser console & excel. Random is not your friend here, as the promise of randomness hurts you.

Another option is the hotwire approach. Basically, you pre-create a bunch of polygons as parts of the town (downtown, east-side, sketchy-south) then, when you create a point, run a `$within` to assign your point to a certain polygon. Return the polygon & no one is the wiser.

Meteor-specific point: Be super sure you have a `{fields: {latLng: 0}}` in your publish function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the maps api will need a location and will return one from functions anyway so people could see it in the console.

You could use the google maps geolocation api to geolocate part of the address (such as an area or partial zip code) and use the results of that for your latlong? You could choose which part you geolocate and therefore have control on how accurate the circle is to the real address.